# How do I pass a batch variable to a VBScript file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, file-io, vbscript, switch-statement

I am making a batch file that takes commands from the user, along with parameters/arguments, and then performs the required action.

At the moment I have (basically):

```
@echo off
set "commands=open archive decrypt encrypt"

set /p CASK=^>
echo %CASK%>TempUserCommand.txt
for /f "delims= " %%c in (TempUserCommand.txt) do set COMMAND=%%c
for /f "tokens=2" %%p in (TempUserCommand.txt) do set PARAM=%%p
del TempUserCommand.txt

for %%i in (%commands%) do (
    if "%%i"=="%COMMAND%" set C=%%i
)

if not "%C%"=="" (
    ::here is where I would like help
) else (
    echo That is not a recognised command.
)
```

What I would like to do is, in the `if` statement (or elsewhere if that would be a better place to do it), is send the variables `%C%` and `%PARAM%`to a `.vbs` file so that I can have it evaluated within a ["SelectCase" statement](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/vbscript_conditionals.asp) (pretty much a switch statement) to find out what command it is and then perform some action (probably edit directories).

I have already seen some questions on this topic, but I don't understand them at all and would really a ppreciate a simply, dumbed-down and explanatory answer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, I think what you want to do is to pass the arguments when calling the VBS file from your batch script.

Then you can access the arguments within VBScript like this:

```
Select Case WScript.Arguments(0)
    Case "Yes"
        MsgBox "Argument is 'Yes'"
    Case "No"
        MsgBox "Argument is 'No'"
End Select
```

The arguments are zero-indexed, so the first argument is 0 (as shown in my example above), the second -- if you provide it -- would be 1, and so on.

Here's an example of how you'd call the script from the batch file and provide an argument:

```
CScript.exe "MyScript.vbs" "Yes"
```

Note, this assumes, I think, that the script is in the same directory as the batch script.  You could always provide the full path to the directory where the script resides if it's in another directory.

Comment: Could you please show how to call the vbs file in the batch?

Comment: So Yes is the argument?

Comment: In my example, correct.  You can pass whatever you want.

Comment: Can you pass more than one argument?